# Standard Model irreducible representation notations

Tags: standard-model, group-theory, notation, representation-theory, complex-numbers

Does anyone know what the significance/meaning of the subscripts on the following notations for the irreps. in the Standard Model?

1. an up, down left-hand fermion (quark) pair $(u,d)_L$ is denoted: $(\bar{3}, \bar{2}, \tfrac{1}{6})_2$, as are $(s,c)$ and $(t,b)$ pairs.
2. a left-handed electron and neutrino is depicted as a pair
   $(e,\nu_e)_L $ with group notation : $(\bar{1}, \bar{2},
   -\tfrac{1}{2})_2$, and similarly for muon and muon-neutrino, and tau, tau-neutrino respectively, they are each also denoted
   $(\bar{1}, \bar{2}, -\tfrac{1}{2})_2$.
3. an up, charm, or top, right-hand quark is denoted : $(\bar{3}, \bar{1}, \tfrac{2}{3})_2$,
4. a down, strange, or bottom, right-hand  quark is denoted as a: $(\bar{3}, \bar{1}, -\tfrac{1}{3})_2$.
5. right-handed leptons are only the electron, muon, and tau and no right-handed neutrinos arelisted, is that correct?
6. gauge gluons $G$ are denoted : $(\bar{8}, \bar{1}, 0)_4$
7. gauge $W$ bosons are denoted : $(\bar{1}, \bar{3},0)_4$
8. gauge $B$ bosons are denoted : $(\bar{1}, \bar{1}, 0)_4$
9. a Higgs boson is denoted : $(\bar{1}, \bar{2}, -\tfrac{1}{2})_1$.

Just a student here, and I am learning the meanings for the brackets, but specifically the question is what is the meaning of the subscripts $(\ldots)_2$,  $(\ldots)_4$,  $(\ldots)_1$ etc.,  after the brackets? I saw this in one talk online by C. Furey here (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0nr50YvWtGU&t=723s), but have not found that notation in any books explaining the irreps.

Listening more carefully at [28:28](https://youtu.be/0nr50YvWtGU?si=Svx5zj5uld4v35OD&t=1708) I heard the subscripts are the "multiplicity of these off-shell states".  So the question now is simply what does *that* mean?  Both "multiplicity" and "off-shell states"? lol.

Update: I get the concept states have a multiplicity, meaning several inequivalent occupancies, or maybe multiple energy levels after some degeneracy splitting, but I am not sure what it means in this context. Group multiplicity. This here [multiplicity-of-an-irreducible-representation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1984432/multiplicity-of-an-irreducible-representation#2338803) only helped a bit, I would not mind a physics minded interpretation.

Comment: Besides the gauge group, fields need to furnish a representation of a certain other group.

Comment: She appears to be deriving these multiplets from an embedding of a broader structure involving Octonions, and getting multiple copies of them. I'd read her most recent (platonic) papers, if I were you.

Comment: Cohl Furey refers to her PhD thesis: https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.09182